# List the employees with same salary

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table emp with columns :-

```
empid   empname mgrid   doj
    1   Steve       2   25-03-2019
    2   Winter      3   26-04-2019
    3   Summer      1   27-05-2019
    4   Autumn      2   28-06-2019
```

and a table sal with columns :-

```
empid   project salary
1   P1  1000000
2   P1  60000
3   P2  5000
4   P3  1000000
```

I want to list name of employees with same salary.
Desired result :-

```
first_employee  second_employee salary
Steve           Autumn          1000000
```

What I tried to do is join emp table with sal and before that was trying to self join sal table. How can I achieve the desired results also is there a way to use union in order to get the results.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if there are more than two employees with the same salary?

I would recommend `group_concat()`:

```
select salary, group_concat(empname order by doj) as empnames
from emp
group by salary
having count(*) > 1;
```